# JQuery/Ajax: Error Handling

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({  
  type: 'POST',  
  url: 'doSomething.php',  
  data: $('#form').serialize(),
  dataType: "json",  
  success: function(data) {
    //Success Message
  },  
  error: function() {
   //Error Message          
  }  
});
```

I have a form input going to a PHP page which I error check on that page. My question is can I send errors (data array) through `error: function(data) {` or is it ONLY for actual errors with Ajax not going through correctly?

If that's the case would I be able to send the error array the success function?

Not sure on how to go about this.

If I could send data from my PHP page to the error function, I wouldn't even know how on the PHP page.

Comment: [Possible Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120002/jquery-ajax-error-handling)

Answer (score 4):

You can raise your own errors, if you do this:

```
$.ajax({  
  type: 'POST',  
  url: 'doSomething.php',  
  data: $('#form').serialize(),
  dataType: "json",  
  success: function(data) {
    //Success Message
  },  
  error: function(req, status, error) {
   alert(req.responseText);      
  }  
});
```

when you throw an exception in your app it will be alerted out. For instance, in PHP you could do:

```
throw new Exception("Something bad happened");
```

You can see more about exceptions [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)

Comment: Thank you, your solution is nowhere else written on the web, whereas it's simple. jQuery/ajax tutorials are wired.

Comment: No problem at all, glad it helped.