# how to run SSE(Server-Sent Events) in Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, server-sent-events

i'd set scripts (background.js) as Background in `manifest.json`.

and write the code blow to background.js:

```
var source = new EventSource('http://localhost:8086/test/');
source.addEventListener('ping', function (e) {
    var notification = webkitNotifications.createNotification(
      'test.png',
      'testTitle',
      'testContent'
    );
    notification.show();
}, false);
```

these code could run correct as normal html page under `http://localhost:8086/`, but it doesn't run at all in the Chrome extension.

I've put `http://localhost:8086/` into "permissions" of manifest.json.

Comment: the "localhost:8086" above should write "http://", but stackoverflow.com do not permit write "http://localhost:8086".

Comment: In the permissions section, you need a wilcard after `..:8086/`, `..:8086/*`. Looks like a duplicate of [Failing AJAX request in a Chrome extension, with correct manifest permissions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9947014/failing-ajax-request-in-a-chrome-extension-with-correct-manifest-permissions).