# http requests not working chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, httpwebrequest, cross-domain

I am developing a chrome extension that requires corss domain XHR. So I need to make get requests to a server and get some text out of it. I am currently loading the unpacked extension from my computer. The script doesn't seem to be working.

Here is my `manifest.json`:

```
{
 "name": "My extension",
 "version": "1.1",
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "description": "Testing http requests",
 "browser_action": {
 "default_icon": "icon.png",
 "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"permissions": [
  "http://*/"
 ]
}
```

And here is the script that performs the get request (from [this](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html) tutorial):

```
function showresponse(){
  var query = document.getElementById("query").value;
  var url = "http://blah.com/search.php?term="+query;
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", url, true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {       
    console.log("hello world");
    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
   }
}
  xhr.send(null);
}
```

The id's etc are set according to my `popup.html` file and that's set up correctly and it includes this js file containing the `showresponse()` function definition.

I also tried packaging my extension to get a `myextension.crx` file after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421933/cross-origin-xmlhttprequest-in-chrome-extensions/9422216#9422216) question and I tried opening the file in my browser, but chrome doesn't allow installing the extension from localhost or unknown servers for security reasons I suppose.

My question is how do I make a cross domain XHR in a chrome extension?

Also the response from the get request to the server is actually an html document and I need to filter some text out of the returned html tags. As I am making a query to a php script, can I receive and therefore play around with the html output if I make a get request in javascript?

How do I go about acheiving this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Failing AJAX request in a Chrome extension, with correct manifest permissions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9947014/failing-ajax-request-in-a-chrome-extension-with-correct-manifest-permissions)