# Check what error value is in ajax callback

Tags: jquery

How can I check what the error value returned is in ajax callback error :

```
$.ajax({
            url: "myurl",       
            type: 'POST',
            dataType : "text",
            data : ({
                json : myjson
            }),
            success : function(data) {

            },
   error : function() {
                alert ('error');
    } 

        });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try accessing these parameters for your error part of the ajax call:

```
error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert(request.responseText);
```

Another example:

```
error: function(xhr) {
                if(xhr.status == 422) {
                  alert(parseErrors(xhr));
                } else {
                  alert('An error occurred while processing the request.');
                }
```

They are part of the ajax call you seperate them with a comma. So a little example:

```
$.ajax({
  success: function(data) {
  },
  error: function(xhr) {
  }
  });
```

**Update:**
Basically xhr.status is the http status number.

```
alert("readyState: "+xhr.readyState);
alert("status: "+xhr.status);
alert("responseText: "+xhr.responseText);
```

Comment: when the error is thrown the value for xhr.status is 0 . Should it be something else if the error is valid ?

Comment: See the update section so you can see what else is in your returned messages for error, so we can see and put them in here.

Answer (score 1):

similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792878/jquery-ajax-error-function)

```
error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    alert(jqXHR.status);
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/