# $.ajax() success won't run function

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

My question regards the `$.ajax()` jQuery method. I can't get the success parameter in `$.ajax()` to work.

This works:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/getCodes.php?codes=billingCodes&parent="+$('#wClient').val(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: window.alert("inside aJax statement")

});
```

This does not:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/getCodes.php?codes=billingCodes&parent="+$('#wClient').val(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(){
        window.alert("inside aJax statement");
    }                       
});
```

In the first case, I get a JavaScript alert window that lets me know the `$.ajax()` I called is working. All that is changed in the second block of code is I put the `window.alert()` inside a `function() {  window.alert();  }`.

The point of this is to verify that the $.ajax is running so I can put some actual useful code in the `function(){}` when the $.ajax runs successfully.

Comment: *"This works:"* No, it doesn't.

Comment: Add an error callback and give us the value of the three passed in arguments.

Comment: Are you sure you're not running on `localhost`? **And** are you sure that the called url ("/getCodes.php?etc..") is correct?

Comment: I'm absolutely running on localhost. yes the getCodes.php is correct, I can see the changes that getCodes.php produces.

Comment: is getCodes.php returning valid json

Comment: you may check your webinspector "network" tab for the response of `getCodes.php`

Comment: or you can navigate to getCodes.phpcodes=billingCodes&parent="+$('#wClient').val() except hardcode the variables.  Then post what the page is displaying here.  Would be helpful to review the json being returned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your second example nothing will happen unless you get a successful call back from the server.  Add an error callback as many here have suggested to see that indeed the ajax request is working but the server is not currently sending a valid response.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/getCodes.php?codes=billingCodes&parent="+$('#wClient').val(),                        
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(response){
        alert(response);        
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert('error');
    }       
});
```

helpful [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792878/jquery-ajax-error-function) in tracking down errors.

Comment: This worked. I was able to output the text status and error message and learned that the JSON was not parsing correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Your first example does nothing whatsoever to prove that the `ajax` call has worked. All it does is prove that the `ajax` function was *reached*, because the values of the properties in the anonymous object you're passing into the `ajax` function are evaluated *before* the function is called.

Your first example is basically the same as this:

```
// THIS IS NOT A CORRECTION, IT'S AN ILLUSTRATION OF WHY THE FIRST EXAMPLE
// FROM THE OP IS WRONG
var alertResult = window.alert("inside aJax statement");
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/getCodes.php?codes=billingCodes&parent=" + $('#wClient').val(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: alertResult

})
```

E.g., **first** the `alert` is called and displayed, **then** the `ajax` call occurs with `success` referencing the return value from `alert` (which is probably `undefined`).

Your *second* example is correct. If you're not seeing the alert in your second example, it means that the `ajax` call is not completing successfully. Add an `error` callback to see why.

Comment: `var alertResult = window.alert("inside aJax statement");` this is not function handler.

Comment: @Saram: Right. But it **is** what the OP is doing in their first example. Read the answer, not just the code block.

Comment: Point making or not. It's not an answer.

Comment: @juk: Sure it is: It's saying: If the second example from the OP isn't triggering the alert, an error is occurring. Look to the error to figure out why.

Comment: It's as close to an answer as we're going to get without input from the author.

Comment: I assumed, that this _"In the first case, I get a JavaScript alert window that lets me know the $.ajax() I called is working"_ means, that OP received info, that call was made, but not response occurred :/

Comment: This may be all correct, but in the end it is not answering the question. I am curios how anybody can answer that question without knowing more. That's why I **commented** on the question itsel..

Comment: @T.j Crowder Nice! haha

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try and use a promise:

```
var promise = $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "/getCodes.php?codes=billingCodes&parent="+$('#wClient').val(),
  dataType: 'json'
});

promise.fail( function() {
  window.alert("Fail!");
});

promise.done( function() {
  window.alert("Success!");
});
```

What this does is saves the `ajax` call to a variable, and then assigns additional functionality for each of the return states. Make sure that the data type you are returning is actually json, though, or you may see strange behavior!

Note that js is single-threaded; the reason your first example works is because it actually executes the code next 'success' and stores the result. In this case there is nothing to store; it just pops an alert window. That means that the ajax call is leaving the client after the alert is fired: use the developer tools on Chrome or equivalent to see this.

By putting a function there, you assign it to do something when the ajax call returns much later in the thread (or, more precisely, in a new thread started when the response comes back).

Comment: This will still fail, but at least it will state that it failed. It would be useful to also include the reason why it fails (the three arguments passed to the fail callback)

Comment: @KevinB That is correct, but I suspect he is not actually getting the response he thinks he's getting. According to the original post, he wants to add this sort of functionality anyway, though.

Answer (score 0):

In first case window.alert is executed immidiatly when you run $.ajax 
In second it run only when you receive answer from server, so I suspect that something wrong in you ajax request

Comment: Thats not correct. `window.alert("inside aJax statement")` is executed **before**  `$.ajax` is called. It is executed at the time the object is created.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you do it right, but your request does not succeeds. Try add also error handler:

```
error: function(){alert("Error");};
```

I guess that dataType does not match or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

It is 100% your second example is correct. Why it does nothing? Maybe because there is no success in the ajax call.
Add "error" handler and check waht does your ajax call return with the browsers' developer tool -> Network -> XHR . This really helps in handling of broken / incorrect ajax requests