# asmx webservice not sending actual error message back to client

Tags: jquery, ajax, asmx

I am using jQuery ajax to call a serverside asmx service.
My client call is looking like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Products.asmx/GetProducts",
    data: "{'searchString':'" + $("#txtSearch").val() + "'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) { ListProducts(data, $scope); },
    error: function (data) { HandleError(data); }
});
```

In most situations it works just perfect.
My problem is that in some situations when an error occur i will only receive the error: 'There was an error processing the request'.
I would like to get the actual error back to the client.
Even in fiddler I can only see the mentioned error message.

Hope someone here can help me.

Comment: I'd try to use a error function with several parameters:  Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown ). More info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792878/jquery-ajax-error-function Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.
In my web.config I had to add CustomErrors=Off.
Now I am receiving the actual error both in my error handling and in fiddler.

Thanks