# How to get response from PHP file as an array using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I am trying to get a full address by entering the postal code in a textbox in HTML form by press a button, I have two files the first one has the ajax function and the second one has the PHP code. I am not sure if my ajax code sending a request to PHP or not, Can anyone help me please?

here is the ajax file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.addressbutton').click(function(){
    ss=  document.getElementById("address").value;
    alert(ss);
    $.ajax({
      url: 'findaddress.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: ss,
      success: function(response){
        var replay = response.postal_code;
        alert(replay);
        document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = response.postal_code;
        document.getElementById('address2').innerHTML = response.route;
        document.getElementById('address3').innerHTML = response.locality;
        document.getElementById('address4').innerHTML = response.postal_town;
        document.getElementById('address5').innerHTML = response.administrative_area_level_2;
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

and here is the PHP code (findaddress.php)

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$ss=$_POST['address'];
$postcode = urlencode($ss);
$url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?
address='.$postcode.'&sensor=false';
$parsedXML = simplexml_load_file($url);

if($parsedXML->status != "OK") {
  echo "There has been a problem: " . $parsedXML->status;
}

$myAddress = array();
foreach($parsedXML->result->address_component as $component) {
  if (is_array($component->type)) {
    $type = (string)$component->type[0];
  } else {
    $type = (string)$component->type;
  }

  $myAddress[$type] = (string)$component->long_name;
}
$f1 = $myAddress['postal_code'];
$f2 = $myAddress['route'];
$f3 = $myAddress['locality'] ;
$f4 = $myAddress['postal_town'] ;
$f5 = $myAddress['administrative_area_level_2'] ;
$f6 = $myAddress['country'];

//print_r($myAddress);
$ORegisertation = array(
  'postal_code' => $f1,
  'route' => $f2,
  'locality' => $f3,
  'postal_town' => $f4,
  'administrative_area_level_2' => $f5,
  'country' => $f6
);
$account_json = json_encode($ORegisertation);
echo $account_json;
?>
```

Comment: Well, what is your ajax result?  Are there any errors in the console? Does it `alert(replay)`?

Comment: Do you have POST request when looking at network tab in developer tools?

Comment: I tried to know what is the response by using alert, but it doesn't run the alert which means there is an error with the response @AdamKonieska

Comment: it gave me these errors in the console

Comment: 'Uncaught TypeError: form.btnAdd is not a function
jquery.equalheights.js:17 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).equalHeights is not a function
signup.php:429 Uncaught ReferenceError: hello is not defined
jquery.equalheights.js:17 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).equalHeights is not a function
9jquery.equalheights.js:17 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).equalHeights is not a function'

Comment: Those console errors seem unrelated... you might want to add some error handling to your ajax request.  There is a good SO post on it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792878/jquery-ajax-error-function

Comment: I will try it. Many thanks  @AdamKonieska

Comment: Please include your HTML code for the better solution

Comment: Your ajax function doesn't look right. you have `data: ss`, you are not assigning a "key" to that data. Therefore I think your `$_POST['address']` is going to return an "**invalid index....**" error. Change to `data: {address: ss}`

Comment: I think that @santosh answer is correct

Comment: could you please look at that answer there @ali i have updated my answer

Comment: check my updated answer @Ali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<form name="frmRegistration" id="signup-form" method="post">
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="address" id="address" class="findaddress"  placeholder="Postal code"/>
        <input type="button" name="addressbutton" class="addressbutton" value="Find" id="findaddress" />
        <input type="text" name="address2" id="address2" class="findaddress"  placeholder="Line 1"/>
        <input type="text" name="address3" id="address3" class="findaddress"  placeholder="Line 2"/>
        <input type="text" name="address4" id="address4" class="findaddress"  placeholder="Line 3"/>
        <input type="text" name="address5" id="address5" class="findaddress"  placeholder="Line 4"/>
    </div>
 </form>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.addressbutton').click(function(){
        ss =  document.getElementById("address").value;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'findaddress.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {address:ss}, //added an index address here
            success: function(response){
                var replay = response.postal_code;
                //innerHTML is not an attribute of text boxes, so changed it to value
                document.getElementById('address').value  = response.postal_code;
                document.getElementById('address2').value = response.route;
                document.getElementById('address3').value = response.locality;
                document.getElementById('address4').value = response.postal_town;
                document.getElementById('address5').value = response.administrative_area_level_2;
            },
            error: function(response) {
                alert("Error: "+response);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }); //added closing brace and bracket
});
```

added comments in script about changes made.

**PHP FILE (findaddress.php)**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$ss         = $_POST['address'];
$postcode   = urlencode($ss);
$url        = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address='.$postcode.'&sensor=false';
$parsedXML  = simplexml_load_file($url);

if($parsedXML->status != "OK") {
    echo "There has been a problem: " . $parsedXML->status;
}

$myAddress = array();
foreach($parsedXML->result->address_component as $component) {
    if(is_array($component->type)) $type = (string)$component->type[0];
    else $type = (string)$component->type;
    $myAddress[$type] = (string)$component->long_name;
}

echo json_encode($myAddress);
die();
?>
```

taken out irrelevant indexing again, and irrelevant statements.

Comment: I tried this way but it is not working, so I am suggeesting to show you my HTML code to have a better idea

Comment: Thanks for you answer @ameen , but it gives me undefined response

Comment: I am searching for that one (lu63ef)  @ameenulla0007

Comment: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=lu63ef&sensor=false check this url, from where you are trying to parse xml, there is no index called locality there. becausse of which you are getting undefined for `response.locality`.

Comment: I think the problem is not with the postal code because I have changed it to another one and it works perfectly and at the same time i have changed the array to send only one value to the ajax but it still says undefined @ameen

Comment: thats what i'm trying to say @Ali, what google returns in xml result, you retrieved it, but while calling it, if the index is not available in result, it returns undefined.

Comment: Good to know that @ali, you are always welcome mate. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending data correctly ..
if you want to get value of address in php which is post from ajax  do this

`data: { address: ss},` // 
And Either add `dataType:'json'` there in your ajax or use  `jsonParse(response)`

you get a string there at your **response** you cannot directly use `response.postal_code;`

Answer (score 0):

There is the ajax code with the html form just to have  a better idea

```
 <form name="frmRegistration" id="signup-form" method="post">

    <div><input type="text" name="address" id="address" class="findaddress"  placeholder="Postal code"/>
        <input type="button" name="addressbutton" class="addressbutton" value="Find" id="findaddress" onclick="javascript:hello()"/>
        <input type="text" name="address2" id="address2" class="findaddress"  placeholder="Line 1"/>
        <input type="text" name="address3" id="address3" class="findaddress"  placeholder="Line 2"/>
        <input type="text" name="address4" id="address4" class="findaddress"  placeholder="Line 3"/>
        <input type="text" name="address5" id="address5" class="findaddress"  placeholder="Line 4"/>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $('.addressbutton').click(function(){
             ss =  document.getElementById("address").value;
             //alert(ss);
             $.ajax({
                 url: 'findaddress.php',
                 type: 'post',
                 data: {address:ss},
                 success: function(response){
                     var replay = response.postal_code;
                     alert(replay);
                     document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = response.postal_code;
                     document.getElementById('address2').innerHTML = response.route;
                     document.getElementById('address3').innerHTML = response.locality;
                     document.getElementById('address4').innerHTML = response.postal_town;
                     document.getElementById('address5').innerHTML = response.administrative_area_level_2;
                 }
             });
             return false;
         }); //added closing brace and bracket
     });
    </script>
</form>
```

Comment: even add up an example what to be searched?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you want to make sure to define the type of response from the server. I like to place dataType:'json' in my $.ajax calls. Then in your PHP code, make sure to add a header of type application/json. This will make a difference with some browsers. I like to read the Response Preview with Google Chrome. It will automatically parse the response; especially helpful with debugging.

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($account_json);
exit;
```