# sending ajax json inputs to appended onclick js function

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, json, ajax

i have a div area in which i added some json input from an ajax success function.

```
function rowClicked(term){
$.ajax({
    url: "/student/transcript_detail",
    data:{term:term},
    on:"/student/transcript_detail",
    method:"POST",
    success: function(responseJson) {
        $('#course-brief-row').empty();
        $('#nomre_term_body').empty();
        $.each(responseJson, function(index,termDetail){
            $("#course-brief-row").append("<a class='style-item' onclick='courseClicked(${termDetail.coirseId},${term})'>" +termDetail.coursename+"<br>"+
                                            termDetail.grade+"<br>"+
                                            termDetail.stat+"<br>"+
                                            "<p><br>&nbsp;</p>"+
                "</a>");""
        });
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("ERROR");
    }

});
```

then i want each added `<a>` tag, to send my json parameter as an input for their `onclick` function calling,

```
function courseClicked(coid,term){
    //do sth
}
```

now i want to know how should i send this argumats?
In other words how should i  write this part:

```
onclick='courseClicked(${termDetail.coirseId},${term})
```

Comment: What is your difficulty? It is the event listener for the onclick. It is the construction of your Json, or another that I do not know.Or you want to send multiple data from a Json through AJAX?

Comment: @JoseMarques what i wrote here is not working, i wanted to know if there is any problem with the syntax?

Comment: First, do you have any errors on your console? Second use the complete function error in your AJAX, for more information use this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792878/jquery-ajax-error-function

Comment: @JoseMarques no there is no error in my console.Besides, i commented all
courseClicked's codes except an alart() and it is still not working.

Comment: Is the data you get from your ajax expected? What kind of data do you receive? To see this go to your browser's console and check the data you receive.

Comment: actually, "termDetail"is a list of defined Object  and term is an Integer.
but the thing is,it works properly without  courseClicked's input parameters.

Comment: Ok your problem it's located when you are constructing your <a> element. The way around this, is creating your <a> element and then apend your onckick function. If you don't know wow to do this give me some time and I will create a exemple for you to folow.

Comment: @JoseMarques I'm really newbie in this area, so it would be very nice of you if you could do me this favor. Thanks in advance for your time!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should suffice I suppose-

```
onclick='courseClicked("+termDetail.coirseId+","+term+")'
```

Its a normal javascript variable that you are passing on anyways.

Try the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/607notn6/.

Comment: Try the fiddle I have added. It works just fine. This is the exact similar of what you are looking for perhaps.

Comment: One of my function argument's is a JSON object directly fetched from server. Any chance that this prevents my function from working? Maybe there must be a different syntax for JSON object.

Comment: You can do a console.log() to check if the json object is populated and you are accessing it correctly. You need to add the statement `console.log(termDetail.coirseId+","+term)` or `alert(termDetail.coirseId+","+term)`just before  `$("#course-brief-row").append...` statement.

Comment: try updating your function declaration to a function expression as `courseClicked = function(coid,term){..}`.

Comment: the json object is populating correctly.but i don't know to  updating my function with such decleration:(

Comment: Just replace `function courseClicked(coid,term){` with `courseClicked = function(coid,term){` wherever you have defined your function courseClicked. https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/

Comment: i tried it but i still get no response.more, i found that in my IDE it has been mentioned that attribute `+termDetail.coirseId+` is not allowed.

Comment: Were the console.log/alert working for you? Could you please share the complete javascript code here or in fiddle?

Comment: it worked!!!!:)hura!
thank you alot, i've just checked some other permutations:)) to see if it works or not and it did.
ps:i used this :
`onclick='courseClicked("+termDetail.coirseId+","+term+")'` syntax and i defined a variable for  `<a>`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the example now you need a little more work.

```js
var var_text = "ola";
var a = document.createElement('a');
var linkText = document.createTextNode("my title text");
a.appendChild(linkText);
a.title = "my title text";
a.setAttribute('onclick', 'fuction_test(var_text)');
document.body.appendChild(a);
function fuction_test(var_text1){
  alert(var_text1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Any doubt, just ask for my help. I will try to help you.

Comment: thanks for your kindness, it guided me alot.
and it's working:)