# Web Method not called in ajax aspx web form

Tags: asp.net, .net, webmethod, jquery-ajax

Here is my ajax request:

```
$("#<% =txtDiagnosisData.ClientID %>").autocomplete({                
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: 'EMR.aspx/SearchDiagnosis',
                        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                          //  response(data.d);
                            alert("success");
                        },
                        error: function (result) {
                            alert("error");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

Here is my function:

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<string> SearchDiagnosis()
{
    return new DataAccess().GetDiagnosis();
}
```

My method is not called from ajax, it always goes to the error part
How to solve this?

Comment: Note that if you are using session then this may break. Use attribute like `[WebMethod(enableSession: true)]` and see if it works. And put the error what you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

There could be an issue that you might be using `Session` variables inside you web method directly or indirectly.

Somewhere in the function `DataAccess().GetDiagnosis();`

In that case use attribute like `[WebMethod(enableSession: true)]` in stead of
`[WebMethod]`
Also try to get the error by implementing error properly like below

```
 error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                  alert('Internal error: ' + jqXHR.responseText);
              } else {
                  alert('Unexpected error.');
              }
          }
```

Ref : [jQuery ajax error function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792878/jquery-ajax-error-function) and see what error exactly you are getting.

Comment: its showing now Unexpected  error,but my web method is still not calling

Comment: @SubrataP can you post the error in you question. Put the values of jqXHR.responseText and all other parameters as well. Also try to call that method from browser directedly. Or use postman to create request.

Comment: after enabling its also not working,and the error is is : unexpected error

Comment: I called it from postman,and the status is 200 Ok,but its returning an html